# Composition of simplicial approximation is again simplicial approximation

Tags: algebraic-topology

If $s:|K^m|\to |L|$ is a simplicial approximation to $f:|K^m|\to |L|$ and $t:|L^n|\to |M|$ is a simplicial approximation to $g:|L^n|\to |M|$. Is $t\circ s: |K^{m+n}|\to |M|$ necessarily a simplicial approximation to $g\circ f:|K^{m+n}|\to |M|?$

I'm sure answer is yes. But i don't know how to prove this. This is one of the question in final exam but i didn't do. Most probably it again comes in my qualifying exam so please I seek the help. Your help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I did not overlook this too quickly, the answer should be yes. We know that, by definition, $s: |K| \to |L|$ is a simplicial approximation to $f: |K| \to |L|$ if $s(x)$ lies in the carrier of $f(x)$ for all $x \in |K|$.

Now, given $f,g,s,t$ as in your question, pick some $x \in |K^{m+n}| = |K|$. Let $f(x) = y$ and $s(x) = y'$. Note that $y$ by definition is not necessarily equal to $y$. What we know is that they do lie in the same interior of some simplex $A$ of $L^n$. Now, we ask if $t\circ s(x)$ is a simplicial approximation to $g\circ f(x)$; that is, we ask that $g(y)$ and $t(y')$ lie in the same interior of some simplex of $M$. We now that $t$ is a simplicial map, i.e. if $A$ is a simplex of $L^n$, $t(A)$ is a simplex of $M$. Therefore, since $y$ and $y'$ both lie in $A$, $t(y),t(y') \in t(A)$. But since $t$ approximates $g$, this means that $g(y) \in t(A)$. This shows that the composition $t\circ s$ is a simplicial approximation to $g\circ f$

Comment: I don't know much about simplicial approximation because i have not covered lot. However, I found the same question in my text book and it says to prove. So taking reference to my text book i must assume it is true..

Comment: why is that $|K^{m+n}|=|K|?$

Comment: Oh i see, maybe I did something wrong? What book are you reading? I am sure there is some proof in your book that $|K^1| = |K|$!

Comment: My book is Basic Topology By M.A. Armstrong. This question is on page 131

Comment: I don't see that proof. Could you please show me little bit about that proof

Comment: Then we are on the same page! Lemma 6.4 on page 126 deals with $|K^1| = |K|$. And the question asks whether or not it is necessarily true, not that it is true and you should prove it.

Comment: I'm sorry, ya i see the proof in the book. Does that question ask to prove or disprove? Its says clearly, if ..., prove...

Comment: Sorry, then we must have different editions! In that case my answer might be wrong

Comment: See my edit! I believe the new solution is correct.

Comment: sorry for late reply, its true that $y$ and $y'$ lies on the interior of some simplex of $L$ because s is simplicial map from $K^m\to L$ but how do we guarantee that they are on the interior of same simplex of $L^n$, as $L^n$ may have very small diameter simplexes as compared to $L$, I apologize otherwise, i may not know other facts.

Comment: I'm sorry, mine book is of old edition and new edition edited it and asked to prove or disprove. I think you were right at the first.

Comment: I think this solution is more correct. It is true what you say, I guess one must have that $s: |K^{m+n}| \to |L^n|$ is a simplicial approximation of $f: |K^{m+n}| \to |L^n|$. Such an $s$ would of course also be a simplicial approximation $|K^m| \to |L|$.

Comment: Thank you, I see my misunderstanding, you are right...